# No XAML was found at the location '/Webview.xaml'

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

in my production app on windows phone, I am getting a crash for which exception is:

```
No XAML was found at the location '/Webview.xaml'.
```

However, I am not using any such XAML in my code. Is it something internal to the SDK? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: By chance is this in regards to upgrading from wp7 to wp8?

Comment: So, I got the scenario - but unable to understand why is it happening.  I have an app in Windows Store that was using 'Webview.xaml'. Now, I have re-written the entire app again - making sure there is no trace of old code anywhere. 

I have searched for this file in the code and csproj but cannot find it anywhere. 

The error is coming to users who have upgraded their app to the latest version ( the one w/o Webview.xaml) from the older version ( which had Webview.xaml)

I am not able to figure out from where the calls are being made or why  is it coming in the first place